# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath generate error in global.asax file

Tags: c#, webforms

I am am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` in global.asax file in one of teh functions to get page related details from database but it fails with following error.

```
`string _result = Helper.GetPageDetails( HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);`
```

Can i use this `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` here i need to get the absolutePath of URL and i am getting following error

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Request is not available in this context
```

I catch this in try{} i get following error message details

`ex = {"Request is not available in this context"}`

Answer (score 0):

This means there is no request associated with the current method call (thread). I am guessing you are calling HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath from a seperate thread than the one from the request. Without further info thats all i can say

Comment: I get this message in try{} catch(exception ex){} `ex = {"Request is not available in this context"}`

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax you use

```
Context.Request
```

as a replacement for

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```